# Load CSV File faster

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I load around 75 CSV files containing one line.

```
For dataRow = 8 To Worksheets("Liste").Range("B65535").End(xlUp).Row

        If Dir(FilePath & Worksheets("List").Cells(dataRow, 2) & ".csv") <> "" Then

            Open FilePath & Worksheets("List").Cells(dataRow, 2) & ".csv" For Input As #2
            Line Input #2, LineFromFile
            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

            itemNumber = 0
            For i = 2 To 367
               Worksheets("Calendar").Cells(dataRow, i).value = Replace(LineItems(itemNumber), Chr(34), "")
               itemNumber = itemNumber + 1
            Next

        End If

        Close #2
    Next
```

The Problem is, that this code is very slow. It takes around 20 seconds to load this data. (27450 data sets, 27,3kb)

Is there a way to speed up the loading? I think my SSD is fast enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two things you can do to speed up your code:

1. Only do the double-quote character replacement once.
2. Write all the data to the cells once.

The second item will probably give you the most speed up as reading/writing cells is time-consuming.  Try this code:

```
If Dir(FilePath & Worksheets("List").Cells(datarow, 2) & ".csv") <> "" Then

    Open FilePath & Worksheets("List").Cells(datarow, 2) & ".csv" For Input As #2
    Line Input #2, LineFromFile
    LineFromFile = Replace(LineFromFile, Chr(34), "")
    lineitems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

    With Worksheets("Calendar")
        .Range(.Cells(datarow, 2), .Cells(datarow, 367)).Value = lineitems
    End With

End If
```

Comment: In addition you could put `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before you start the loop and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after the loop has finished. This way, if you have formulas that are dependent on the values in your target range (or ANY volatile functions) then they only need to update once instead of 75 times.

Comment: It helps me a lot :) Now I can speed up all of my code :) Before: 20 seconds, afterwards: instant :D